# Automatic field creation on form submission

Tags: python, django

I am writing a simple blog app and I'm currently in the position where I need to implement comments on a blog post. So, I have two models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('articles:article-detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    post_id = models.IntegerField()
```

and a `ModelForm`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Article, Comment

class CommentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'content',
            'author',
        ]
```

...when I submit the form, I want my Comment's `post_id` field to be automatically generated and correspond to my Article's `id`, i.e. the comment should be located on the page where it was submitted.

Here is my `views.py`:

```
def article_detail_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=id)
    comment_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        comment_form.save()
        comment_form = CommentModelForm()
    context = {
        'object': obj,
        'comments': comments,
        'comment_form': comment_form
    }
    return render(request, 'articles/article_detail.html', context)
```

Any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change the `Comment` model in order to replace `post_id` with a foreignkey field. It allows to keep a better link between comments and articles.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # cascade will delete the comments if the article is deleted.
```

Then you only have to change the comment_form validation :

```
if comment_form.is_valid():
    comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
    comment.post_id = obj 
    comment.save()
    comment_form = CommentModelForm()
```

`save(commit=False)` allows to create the `Comment` instance without saving it to database and allow us to specify the `post_id` with the article instance `obj` defined above. Then comes the final commit `comment.save()`.

---

If you prefer to not change your model, you can follow the same logic and replace

`comment.post_id = obj` by `comment.post_id = id`.